# How to get JSON property name php

Tags: php, json, oop

I have a folowing JSON file:

```
{"ver":2,"sb":[some array],"ld":[some array] ,"hd":[some array]}
```

I try to ger property names with next code:

```
$path='./datafiles/jsonTest.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($path));
$properties=get_object_vars($data);
foreach($properties as $propName){
    echo $propName.'<br>';
}
```

but as result I get:

```
2
Array
Array
Array
```

when I need:

```
'ver'
'sb'
'ld'
'hd'
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I saw that there is an answer already but for the next time you can use a JSON visualizer like http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm With it you can see easily how to access the needed fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the resulting output as an object, you coud use the array version of `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

$properties = array_keys($data);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also try using json_decode to give you an associative array

```
$path='./datafiles/jsonTest.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($path),true);
foreach($data as $name => $value){
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the key?

```
foreach($properties as $key => $propName){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use reflection to get the properties names (http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) - which would be the elegant way - or you decide not to decode the Json data and extract the names and values with manual string operations.